# How to know which IP address is used for my DNS queries on macOS?

Tags: vpn, dns, macos

I'm not an expert, only have basic knowledge about all this but I'd like to understand what's going on so please bear with me.

I'm currently using a VPN (IKEv2 protocol) on a macOS system and I can see my VPN configuration in the network settings (System Preferences => Network).

With that VPN, I'm also using an app made to encrypt my DNS requests (AdGuard).

I noticed the following: when AdGuard is on, it basically overrides the VPN's DNS settings. In fact, when doing leak tests, AdGuard's DNS is showing up instead of the VPN's. Which is a good thing and what I'm actually looking for.

Now, AdGuard is using a VPN slot in macOS network settings as you can see below:

[image: AdGuard VPN slot]

It's not using it as a VPN per se, because AdGuard doesn't have one.

Then, when I'm looking at the AdGuard's slot characteristics, I can see no IP address:

[image: AdGuard's IP address]

So I was wondering: when my computer is making DNS queries to AdGuard's DNS, are those queries made with my real IP address or the VPN's one?

Is there something I can do to figure this out?

**Edit :** here is my route table :

```
Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags           Netif Expire
default            link#20            UCSg           ipsec0       
default            192.168.1.254      UGScIg            en1
```

and

```
Internet6:
Destination                             Gateway                         Flags           Netif Expire
default                                 fe80::%utun0                    UGcIg           utun0       
default                                 fe80::%utun1                    UGcIg           utun1       
default                                 fe80::%utun2                    UGcIg           utun2       
::1                                     ::1                             UHL               lo0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the DNS servers are set via the VPN (as in they override what you use when NOT on a VPN) or the VPN tunnel is set to tunnel-all (as in they install a default route into your route table, which will have a lower distance/metric than your usual default route), then the request is a part of the encapsulated traffic and is routed through the VPN tunnel, meaning publicly it would use the VPN’s public IP address from the remote node your session is established with.

Comment: The VPN actually has DNS servers set by default but overridden by AdGuard's DNS.
I am unsure if the VPN is configured in full-tunnel or split-tunnel. Is there any way I could know this? I would guess that any VPN (that's not your own) is configured in full-tunnel and split-tunnel is something you have to actually configure yourself but I wouldn't bet on it.

Comment: @spectral-hardware Easily. If you see that the tunnel installs more than 1 route (anything other than ONLY a default route) it’s in split-tunnel mode.  Your guess is not necessarily true. Depending on the environment, such as if a client/customer requests it, the tunnels can be whatever they want. They can even be different per user (one may have split-tunnel while others have tunnel-all).  If you want to see which address will be used to reach which DNS server, it’s as easy as looking at your route table on your Mac to see which route encompasses the destination you’re looking for.

Comment: @spectral-hardware If you want to see your route table on your Mac, open up a terminal session and then type `netstat -rn`.

Comment: I checked the netstat -rn command and I've noticed the AdGuard's DNS address (94.140.15.15) uses the ipsec0 Netif. So I'm guessing that all of my DNS queries are made with my VPN's IP, is that correct?
Now that I've seen this table, more questions were raised ... I checked the "default" routes as you advised me. In the "Internet" section, I can see 2 default routes. One uses "ipsec0" (tunnel?) and the other "en1". This one is my default router IP though. Then, in the "Internet6" section, I have 3 default routes and all of them use "utunx". To me, it looks like full tunnel. What do you think?

Comment: @spectral-hardware Correct. If you see a route for 0.0.0.0/0 bound to the ipsec0 interface (unless you have a more explicit route sending traffic to a different next hop), and it has a lower metric than the other 0.0.0.0/0 route on en1, all of your traffic will egress over the VPN.  If you’d like, you can edit your post to include the route table so I can see for myself - just make sure you use proper formatting and don’t post it as a screenshot.

Comment: There you go with the default routes.

Comment: @spectral-hardware Looks good, and what you assumed and what I said in the previous comment are correct.

Comment: Great. Again, thanks for your help and patience on this. I learned pretty useful things.

Comment: @spectral-hardware No problem. Happy to help.

Comment: @spectral-hardware Would you mind upvoting my answer too? I know you marked it as accepted already but that doesn’t automatically upvote at the same time (which is a stupid design flaw, imo).  If you don’t want to, no worries.

Comment: I did, actually. But as it seems I don't have enough reputation, the website won't let me. However my "feedback has been recorded" (don't know what it means though).

Comment: Did you get something for the accepted solution thing?

Comment: @spectral-hardware Yeah.  15 point. The more points, the more you can do on the site, and the easier it is to help and direct people.  If the upvote had worked too, it would be a few more.